# slide transition using UIView.transition() method

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3

I have and table view and when the user clicks a button I want it to reload it's data and change numerous other things. Sadly, my users have not been satisfied with the available options for the transitions/animations, and wanted a sliding transition. I couldn't find anything online to do this, however. Here is my code:

```
 UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5,options: .transitionCurlUp,animations:
            { () -> Void in
                self.schedule.reloadData()
                self.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                let dayOfWeek = self.week[self.getDayOfWeek(self.currentDate)!-1]
                var forReturn = dayOfWeek.getCourseNumber()
                if forReturn>3{
                    forReturn = forReturn + 1
                    self.refreshButton.isHidden = false
                    self.noClasses.isHidden = true
                }else{
                    self.refreshButton.isHidden = true
                    self.noClasses.isHidden = false
                }
                self.changeWeek()
                let startDate = self.formatter.string(from: self.startDateBase)
                if self.currentDate == startDate{
                    self.other1.text = "Today's Schedule"
                }else{
                    self.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    self.currentDate = self.formatter.string(from: self.date)
                    self.other1.text = dayNames[self.getDayOfWeek(self.currentDate)!-1] + " Schedule"
                }
        }, completion: nil
        );
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you want a sliding transition as the cell is reloaded, have you done [`reloadRows`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) or [`reloadSections`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614954-reloadsections) with a [`UITableViewRowAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewrowanimation) of `.right` or `.left`? That's the easiest way to get slide animation of the update of a row or table.

Comment: The problem is I want to animate the change of the entire page. Not just the table view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go old school on this:

- take a snapshot of the `view`;
- add it to the view hierarchy;
- apply offsetting transforms to the snapshot view and the `view`, itself;
- animate the restoration of the main view's `transform` back to `.identity`; and
- removing the snapshot view when done with the animation.

Thus:

```
let snapshotView = snapshot()
view.addSubview(snapshotView)
snapshotView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -view.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

// do whatever updates to the views you want here
tableView.reloadData()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    self.view.transform = .identity
}, completion: { _ in
    snapshotView.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

For the snapshot, I used:

```
func snapshot() -> UIView {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame = view.bounds
    return imageView
}
```

---

By the way, you can also use [`snapshotView(afterScreenupdates:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview), which is faster than `drawHierarchy`, but it doesn't work in 7+ simulator for some reason (see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63438), so I'm not 100% comfortable with it. But if you wanted to do that, you'd do replace the `shapshotView` declaration with:

```
let snapshotView = view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)!
```